# regex to allow "www" (optional) but exclude subdomains on Google Analytics

Tags: regex, subdomain

I am attempting to exclude all subdomains but still allow www. (optional)
And then anything after the domain name is optionally allowed

Here is what I'm looking for:

```
www.domain.com       // true
domain.com           // true
sub.domain.com       // false
domain.com/hello     // true
www.domain.com/hello // true
```

Here is what I have:

```
^(?i)(?:www\.)?domain.com.*
```

This is still allowing other subdomains.

I have tried

```
^(?i)(?:www\.)(?![-\w.])?domain.com.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(www\.)?domain\.com(\/.*)?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jM3zK5/1)

Comment: weird. That works on regex demo site. I am looking to use this for google analytics. And when I plug this into google analytics all subdomains are still shown. (using a custom segment - so it filters the data view)

Comment: ^(domain\.com|www\.domain\.com\)
does not work either

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make it work on GA but this regex seems to be quite simple.

Comment: In GA, you don't need to escape forward slashes. So maybe try this: ^(www\.)?domain\.com(/.*)?